# i m facing following error using first time eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

this error occurred what to do run the application??

```
Initializing AppEngine server
25/06/2010 9:16:57 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
25/06/2010 9:16:59 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Documents and Settings\kk\workspace\First\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
25/06/2010 9:16:59 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Documents and Settings\kk\workspace\First\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
25/06/2010 2:47:14 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl start
INFO: The server is running at http://localhost:8888/
```

edit (1) ::

when i m running the program http://localhost:8888/first

(copied from a comment to my answer)

i face Error 403 FORBIDDEN what to do now?

in the firstservlet.java i write only the following code

```
package first; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import javax.servlet.http.*; 
public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet { 
  /** 
  * 
  */ 
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain"); 
    resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world"); 
  } 
}
```

whats the wrong??

Comment: What makes you think there is an error? It says it has successfully started the server.

Comment: Also check the web.xml of your First war. the problem is within the war, example the welcome file or the dirAllowed settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 403 Forbidden is a HTTP status code returned by a web server when a user agent requests a resource that the server does not allow them to

(wikipedia)

The server is up and running, accepted you request but can't respond because you're not allowed to access some resource. So the problem is inside the `First`application, maybe this aplication trys to access some file system resources and the server does not have sufficient privileges.

Comment: in the firstservlet.java i write only the following code

package first;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class FirstServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
    /**
  * 
  */
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println("Hello, world");
    }
}

whats the wrong??

Comment: @Keyur Shah - Have you mapped the FirstServlet within web.xml so that it can be accessed?